# Write Get-ADUser query result to table using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to pull a list of users from a table, lookup their email using Get-ADUser and write the result back to a SQL table. So far I can save the resultset to a csv. file, but how to write to a table instead.

```
$connString = "Server = 'sql1'; Database = 'test'; Integrated Security = True"
$QueryText = 'SELECT [ADUser] FROM [test].[dbo].[Users]'
$SqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $connString
$SqlCommand = $SqlConnection.CreateCommand()
$SqlCommand.CommandText = $QueryText
$DataAdapter = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $SqlCommand
$dataset = new-object System.Data.Dataset
$DataAdapter.Fill($dataset)

$dataset.Tables[0] | ForEach {
Get-ADUser -identity $_.ADUser -Properties Name, SamAccountName,mail |
Select Name, SamAccountName, mail |
Export-CSV C:\Users\export3.csv -Append -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use the awesome PowerShell community DBATools module for this.  It's written by some long-time PowerShell and SQL MVPs and makes this an easy job.

First, install the module with

```
Install-Module DBATools
```

The module has two commands we'll need to make this work.  First, you convert regular PowerShell objects into a SQL DataTable by using `ConvertTo-DBADataTable`, then you write it to a SQL DB using `Write-DBADataTable`.

So here's what that looks like.  I start by creating a new SQL DB called `DBATools` on my SQL instance named `SCCM`.  Next,  I get a list of users I want to insert into a table.

[image]

Next, I pipe this into `| ConvertTo-DbaDataTable` and store it in a variable.

```
$DataTable = get-aduser -Filter * | select Name,DistinguishedName,SurName | ConvertTo-DbaDataTable
```

And finally, I run `Write-DBADataTable` to write these rows to a new table (creating the new table by adding `-AutoCreateTable`)

```
Write-DbaDataTable -SqlInstance SCCM -Database DBATools `
  -InputObject $DataTable -Table UserTable -AutoCreateTable
```

Now, I go over to SSMS and refresh to see my new table has been created, with appropriate columns!  Awesome, and easey-peasey!

[image]